# convergence of $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{lnx}{\sqrt[3]x(x+1)}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I need help checking if the integral:

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt[3]x(x+1)}$$

converge or diverge.

I tried comparing to bigger integrals using $\ln x \lt x$ or making the denominator smaller but without success.

any suggestions?

Comment: it converges. It can be seen easily using asymptotics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{2\pi^2}{3}$$

Comment: Note that for $0<x<1$,$$\left|\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt[3]x(x+1)}\right|<\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt[3]x}$$And for $x>1$,$$\left|\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt[3]x(x+1)}\right|<\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{4/3}}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I made a mistake about the lower limit. it's 1

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{4/3}}$ diverge right? so I don't think it helps.

Comment: @segevp Nope, $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{4/3}}~\mathrm dx<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Bertrand integral.

We have $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^\frac 65\frac {\ln (x)}{x^{\frac 13}(1+x)}=0$$

because $\frac 65 <\frac 43$.

$\frac 65>1\implies $ the integral converges.

For $x $ large enough

$$0 <\frac {\ln (x)}{x^\frac 13 (1+x)}<\frac {1}{x^\frac 65} $$

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $x\mapsto z^3$ leads to an absolutely convergent integral:

$$ I = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt[3]{x}(1+x)}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto z^3}{=} \color{blue}{9\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{z \log z}{1+z^3}\,dz}\stackrel{z\mapsto t^{-1}}{=}9\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(t)}{1+t^3}\,dt\tag{1}$$
that can be easily computed: since $\int_{0}^{1}t^k(-\log t)\,dt = \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$,
$$ I = 9\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(3k+1)^2}\approx\color{blue}{8.56365942}.\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compare it to $$\frac{\ln x}{x^{4/3}}.$$

This, incidentally, can be compared to some multiple of$$\frac{\ln(x^{1/1000})}{x^{4/3}},$$which can then be compared to$$\frac1{x^{4/3-1/1000}};$$note that the exponent in the denominator is strictly greater than $1$.

Comment: Of course, I could have used any small enough number other than $1/1000$.